# Nested RecyclerView with boolean array?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app with a dynamic number of switches to connect to a device. Here is my model class:

```
public class SwitchModel {

private String product;
private String deviceId;
private ArrayList<Boolean> switchPool;

public SwitchModel(String product, String deviceId, ArrayList<Boolean> switchPool) {
    this.product = product;
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
    this.switchPool = switchPool;
}
```

As you can see, I have only a product string for user input. A device id provided by the API and a dynamic number of switches.
I want to my final app functions like this:

[image]

I tried to do this task by using a nested `RecyclerView`:

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder> {

Activity context;
private ArrayList<SwitchModel> modelList;

public MainAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<SwitchModel> modelList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelList = modelList;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SwitchModel model = modelList.get(position);
    holder.productName.setText(model.getProduct());
    ChildAdapter childAdapter = new ChildAdapter(model.getSwitchPool());
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    holder.rvChild.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    holder.rvChild.setAdapter(childAdapter);
}
```

And here is the code for my Child Adapter:

```
public class ChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Boolean> switches;

public ChildAdapter(ArrayList<Boolean> switches) {
    this.switches = switches;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Boolean model = switches.get(position);

    holder.switchButton.setChecked(model);

    holder.switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("myResponse", "onCheckedChanged: " + view.isChecked());
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

The `RecyclerView` sets the checked value of the switch correctly. But my problem is as you can see in my child view I have bound a boolean for each index of array list, but when I call for a check change listener it does not return the exact switch number of the product. It would be great if anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps try to leverage a [ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) from Google.

In essence, you can supply N adapters with N data and update/handle them individually. I have never *tried* to do this by myself, and I don't want to make it sound like it's an easy thing to do, but it appears to "perhaps fit the use-case" you describe.

Someone has [already done an expandable recyclerview using concat adapter](https://medium.com/codeshake/create-an-expandable-recyclerview-with-the-mergeadapter-254fd671fa5b) so perhaps this would point you in the right direction before you get your hands dirty trying to make it work.